# Counting people in an image using opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to openCV and python both. I am trying to count people in an image. The image is supposed to be captured with an overhead camera or the way a CCTV camera is placed. 
I have converted the colored image into binary image and then inverted the binary image. Then I used bitwise OR on original and inverted binary image so that the background is white and the people are colored.

- How to count these people? Is it necessary to use a classifier or can i just count the contours ,if yes then how to count them?

Plus there are some issues with the technique I'm using.

- Faces of people are light in color so sometimes only hair are getting extracted.
- The dark objects other than people also get extracted.
- If the floor is dark it won't give the binary image that is needed.

So is there any other method to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but it may worth to check [there](https://realpython.com/blog/python/face-recognition-with-python/).

It explain how to perform face recognition using openCV and python in pictures and extand it to webcam [here](https://realpython.com/blog/python/face-detection-in-python-using-a-webcam/), it's not quite what your looking for but may give you some clue/

Comment: I don't want to use a video, but i'll try if this can work with an image. Thank you.